# Introduction to Probability with Texas Hold’em Examples

Tags: probability, statistics

In a game of Texas Hold’em, what is the probability that your hole cards will be the same suit?

Answer (score 1):

Your hole cards are chosen at random from the full deck.  Given any card picked as the first, you will have 51 remaining choices from the deck for the second card.

Out of those 51 remaining, 12 will have the same suit.  So the chance of being dealt two suited cards is 12/51 or 23.5%.

Comment: Thank You!!!!!!

Comment: If an answer helped you, be sure to click the check mark to accept it.